# Matching values in dataset and rewrite to remove some type II error

Tags: r, replace, merge, find

I have predictions from two datasets. The prediction1 is highly correlated with actual values and prediction2 is not. My actual data contain 50,000 predictions with the same kind of structure. I would like to match all the values that are the same from predictions 1 and predictions 2 (0,0 and 1,1), but for predictions 1 and 2 that do not match (0,1 or 1,0), I would like to change the predictions 2 string from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. I have the predictions = prediction data frame. Want I want the data to look like = observed data frame. Hence prediction1 = observed1 and predictions2 = observed2 (what I want to look like).

```
#--------Dataset
prediction1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
prediction2<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
predictions<-data.frame(prediction1,prediction2)

#--------Want I want the dataset to look like
observed1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
observed2<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
observed<-data.frame(observed1,observed2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want two columns that both hold the result of `prediction1`.

```
observed <- data.frame(observed1 = prediction1, 
                       observed2 = prediction1) # Both use prediction1
```